# RootNamespace not being used as namespace prefix

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, .net-6.0

I recently created a new .net6 project and moved my source code into it.
I've set the following in the project file

```
<RootNamespace>$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_"))</RootNamespace>
```

In the project properties there is a section at the bottom of Application -> General there is a "Default namespace" which also has "$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_"))"

For the sake of this question I have omitted the solution completely and let's assume my project structure is as follows

MyProject (this is a project with project file MyProject.csproj)

- DB (this is a folder in the project)

  - MySQL (this is a sub-folder under the DB folder)
  - MSSQL (this is a sub-folder under the DB folder)
- UI (this is a folder in the project)

If I add a new class at the root level of my project it's namespace is MyProject however if I add a new class to DB it's namespace is DB.

I expect this to be MyProject.DB

Similarly if I add a new class to the MSSQL project I get a namespace of
DB.MSSQL whereas I expect this to be MyProject.DB.MSSQL

I have tried hard coding the $(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_")) as MyProject but this doesn't help.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't have "child" projects. If "DB" is a project, then "MSSQL" is not a project. Maybe it's a *folder* under the "DB" project? It's unclear what each node of this structure supposed to be. And, if "DB" *is* a project, represented by `DB.csproj`, then the `MSBuildProjectName` property is exactly as what you should expect it to be because it's [defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2022) as *"The file name of the project file without the file name extension; for example, MyApp."*.

Comment: The *solution* name (ostensibly what "MyProject" represents, but again, unclear) is not part of that.

Comment: If DB is a project, then "MSSQL" is not a project. make a subfolder of the db project？

Comment: Just to be clear I have omitted the solution name from this example completely. I will update the question to make this more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As strange as this sounds, the problem was with WebView2 version 1.0.1343.22
Updating to version 1.0.1370.28 resolved the issue

I did also recreate this in a fresh solution with only 1 project and no other dependencies to ensure that is the case.

Interestingly the default using statements are also different.

With version 1.0.1343.22 installed, creating a new class file you get

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DB.MsSQL
{
    internal class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

Whereas with version 1.0.1370.28 a new class file looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebView2NamespaceIssue.DB.MsSQL
{
    internal class Class2
    {
    }
}
```

Both of these classes were created in the same folder of the same project.
The only difference was changing the version of WebView2 being referenced